# Angular hybrid app - angular 2 router not working

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing, aot

I am trying to run hybrid app wit angular 2 components. Following are the setup i have done to run hybrid app, i am able to run the application and "my-app" component is also initialized in this hybrid app, but when i am trying to access a component (FirstComponent) using route("/first"), it loads the FirstComponent but automatically redirects to my default angular 1 route.

index.html

```
<base href="/hybridApp/">
<my-app></my-app>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>' +
  '<div ng-view></div>',
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        UpgradeModule,
        RouterModule,
        FirstModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {
    constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }
    ngDoBootstrap() {
    }
}
```

first.module.ts

```
export class Ng1Ng2UrlHandlingStrategy implements UrlHandlingStrategy {
    shouldProcessUrl(url: any) {
        return url.toString().startsWith("/first");
    }

    extract(url: any) {
        return url;
    }

    merge(url: any, whole: any) {
        return url;
    }
}

const routes : Routes = [

    {
        path :'first',

        component: FirstComponent
    }
]



@NgModule({
    imports:[
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ useHash: true, initialNavigation: true, enableTracing: true })
    ],
    exports:[

    ],
    declarations:[
        FirstComponent
    ],
    providers:[
        { provide: UrlHandlingStrategy, useClass: Ng1Ng2UrlHandlingStrategy }
    ]
})
export class FirstModule {}
```

first.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector:'first-component',
    templateUrl:'src/app/first.component.html',
    styleUrls:['src/app/first.component.css']
})

export class FirstComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit(){
        console.log("first component rendered..")
    }

    constructor(
        private route:ActivatedRoute
    )
    {}
}
```

main.ts

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
    const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
    upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['angular1App']);
});
```

I am able to see logs from my FirstComponent "first component rendered.." but instead of staying on that route it redirects to default route of angular1 app.

Here are the logs as i see through approach suggested by @jeffrey

```
NavigationStart {id: 8, url: "/first"}
   NavigationStart {id: 8, url: "/first"}
   RoutesRecognized {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: "/first", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
   RoutesRecognized {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: "/first", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
   GuardsCheckStart {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
   GuardsCheckStart {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
   GuardsCheckEnd {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}
   GuardsCheckEnd {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}
   ResolveStart {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
   ResolveStart {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
   ResolveEnd {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
   ResolveEnd {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
   NavigationEnd {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: "/first"}
   NavigationEnd {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: "/first"}
   NavigationEnd {id: 8, url: "/first", urlAfterRedirects: "/first"}
   NavigationStart {id: 9, url: "/auth"}
   NavigationStart {id: 9, url: "/auth"}
   NavigationStart {id: 9, url: "/auth"}
   GuardsCheckStart {id: 9, url: "/auth", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
   GuardsCheckStart {id: 9, url: "/auth", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
   GuardsCheckStart {id: 9, url: "/auth", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
   GuardsCheckEnd {id: 9, url: "/auth", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}
   GuardsCheckEnd {id: 9, url: "/auth", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}
   GuardsCheckEnd {id: 9, url: "/auth", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}
   NavigationEnd {id: 9, url: "/auth", urlAfterRedirects: "/auth"}
   NavigationEnd {id: 9, url: "/auth", urlAfterRedirects: "/auth"}
   NavigationEnd {id: 9, url: "/auth", urlAfterRedirects: "/auth"}
```

Comment: Which router are you using with the AngularJS app?

Comment: i am using ngRoute

Comment: Here is an article on [How to Divide the routes between the Angular 1 and the Angular 2 routers](https://vsavkin.com/migrating-angular-1-applications-to-angular-2-in-5-simple-steps-40621800a25b)

Comment: Can you add import statement parts too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm tryng to use my ui-router form angularjs with angular 5 application. Now I'm having some problems with http_interceptor, anyway, first I have to downgrade app-component, and insert in my index.js file. second I try to know if the url handling strategy is working and angular 5 starts to manage the routes. Third, I have to inject the angular5 urlHandling strategy and routes from angular5 in angularjs module. After that my angular 5 was worked. I found a gist about this after hours of search.

**Link:**

### [Gist](https://gist.github.com/zaenk/21e8bee3071f339aed27f411822bb8d9)

Answer (score 0):

**To see what the router does, *before, during and after* redirecting, add this to your FirstComponent:**

```
constructor(
  private router: Router
) {
  this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
    console.log(e)
  });
}
```

You have to dig through the event-logs a bit, but it may give you valuable insights.

---

**If you encounter this problem only for deployment, try the following:**

If you are using an apache server, add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

If you are using a different server such as NGinx, IIS or Firebase, [take a look here for more configurations](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#development-servers) as recommended by the Angular team.

Comment: Its happening in development as i am doing this first time and none of my route is  working. Also the same thing happens both ways, using routerLink or directly entering the url.

Comment: Also, even when i setup my hybrid application using this approach https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngUpgrade-without-preparation. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I've updated my answer with a way to get a lot of debug info from the router, you should try it.

Comment: Jeff, i have updated the question with relevant logs using your approach.

Comment: Thanks. As you can see, after `firstNavigationEnd` it triggers another `firstNavigationStart` (now with `id: 9`). What happens if you set `initialNavigation: false`? Also, do you happen to have some guards or a canActivate added to your router, which causes the redirect to `/auth`?

Comment: Tried using initialNavigation: false, but the result is still same. Also as i shared the router settings also, i didn't have any guards for my routes.

Comment: Hm, I have no idea why this happens, and it's hard for me to guess what happens *exactly* during the redirect. I'll get back to you later today..

Comment: Still have no idea.. Maybe you can post the complete `const routes`. I see the router gets forwarded to `/auth`, but I don't see it in your `routes` config.

Comment: I have just started with hybrid application setup and as of now, i only have this single route in my project as mentioned above.

Comment: Then where does `/auth` come from?

Comment: By single route in application, i mean, in angular 2. and /auth is in angularjs